# Get hue (HSV/HSB) value of RGB using Emgu C# yields wrong result

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors, rgb, emgucv

I am using [EMGU.CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) 3.4.1.2976 (latest) library to analyze images but I am not getting the results I expect. I benchmark against [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) but any image package should do.

To test functionality, I am analyzing a simple blue 640x320 jpeg like below. The RGB value for this image is 0,0,255.

[image: test image to get hue value from]

Hue histogram from ImageJ (value is 170, count 2048000)

[image: Hue histogram of blue jpeg]

Using code below I get a spike at 120 instead of the 170 - count 2048000 is correct though.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    public void AnalyzeEmgu(object image)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[256];

        using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)image)
        {
            using (Image<Hsv, byte> hsvImage = new Image<Hsv, byte>(bmp))
            {
                Image<Gray, byte>[] channels = hsvImage.Split();
                Image<Gray, byte> imgHue = channels[0];

                for (int x = 0; x < imgHue.Rows; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < imgHue.Cols; y++)
                    {
                        var b = imgHue.Data[x, y, 0];
                        arr[b]++; // fill array with Hue data. Add 1 (++) to count amount.
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        GC.Collect();
        OnImageFinished(arr); // return array 
    }

  // call function.
  Bitmap bmp =new Bitmap(@"c:\test\blue.jpg");
  AnalyzeEmgu(bmp);
```

**UPDATE**

It turns I need to convert to a different color space but it still is not 100 % correct. `arr` now returns 171 instead of 170. It is of course only a slight difference but for more complex images it is noticable.

What can be the problem?

```
    public void AnalyzeEmgu(object image)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[256];

        using (Mat orig = new Mat((string)image, ImreadModes.Color))
        {
            using (Mat hsv = new Mat())
            {
                // convert color to HSV here.
                CvInvoke.CvtColor(orig, hsv, ColorConversion.Bgr2HsvFull);
                Mat[] channels = hsv.Split();

                using (Image<Bgr, byte> img = channels[0].ToImage<Bgr, byte>())
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < img.Rows; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < img.Cols; y++)
                        {
                            var b = img.Data[x, y, 0];
                            arr[b]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                channels[1].Dispose();
                channels[2].Dispose();
            }
        }
        GC.Collect();
    }

    OnImageFinished(arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use ImageJ or EMGU.CV but I'll share some things to consider...

**(1)**

> Correct hue value is 240 (not 170) degrees.

The hue for blue (0,0,255) is **240** degrees in the color wheel. Note that it can also be said as **-120**.
 
This logic might explain why you *"get a spike at 120"* for that specific hue in`AnalyzeEmgu` function.

Can recover from minus mode by adding 360. *Eg:* `myHue = (-120) + 360;` which gives result: `240`.

[image]

(Above) Image credit: http://www.graphic-design.com/Photoshop/color_cast/visible_color_spectrum.html

**(2)**

> Why does Hue histogram from ImageJ give **170**?

If you look at the Image histogram it maxes at **255** but wheel/circle should max at **360**. No logic why they did it like that, but it can be fixed:

```
IF: 360 / 255 = 1.4117647058823529411764705882353
THEN: 170 * 1.4117647058823529411764705882353 = 240 degrees.
```

**(3)**

> *"Using code below I get a spike at 120 instead of the 170"*

Try

```
myHue = 360 - 120; //gives 240
```

In the image below made in Photoshop, I am showing that (starting from top) if we get to blue it is correctly listed as **240** degrees and is found at 88 pixels "distance" when travelling downwards.

The opposite is to travel upwards from bottom, and we see that the same distance of 88 pixels now gives **120** (a green hue).

Your code's color wheel is flipped (upside down). Compare **A** against **B** side by side.
Photoshop uses system **A**, but your value suggests your code thinks like system **B**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer / accepted. I have learned that Emgu.CV returns degrees and when using "Bgr2HsvFull" those are transformed into the 8bpp color scale (hence the 170). As for the difference between 170 and 171, this is related to rounding. Emgu.CV / OpenCV is using BGR instead of RGB.